# How to find orientation of a surface using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I was inspired by [Pokemon GO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeGE8a_WQMc) and wanted to make a simple prototype for learning purposes. I am a total beginner in image processing.

I did a little research on the subject. Here is what I came up with. In order to place any 3D model in the real world, I must know the orientation. Say if I am placing a cube on a table:

1) I need to know the angles $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\alpha$ where $\theta$ is the rotation along the global UP vector, $\phi$ is the rotation along the camera's FORWARD vector and $\alpha$ is rotation along camera's RIGHT vector.

2) Then I have to multiply these three rotation matrices with the object's transform using these Euler angles.

3) The object's position would be at the center point of the surface for protyping.

4) I can find the distance of the surface using android's camera's inbuilt distance estimation using focal length. Then I can scale the object accordingly.

Is there any more straight forward way to do this using OpenCV or am I going in the right track?

[image: Illustration]